# Ogre3d restoreConfig causes app to hang on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, opengl, ubuntu, ogre3d

Building an app for Ubuntu using Ogre3D, CEGUI, OIS which is now all compiling and running as expected. Having got the basic app running I decided to now build a custom config file which I can store both graphics settings (ie. resolution, fullscreen, etc) as well as other configurable settings I will need in the app down the track.

As a starting point I changed from calling mRoot->showConfigDialog() at each startup to :

```
if(!mRoot->restoreConfig())
    mRoot->showConfigDialog();
```

this was meant to restore the config from the 'ogre.cfg' file which exists and so it did, but got to loading a skybox texture on the first scene create and just sat there doing nothing.

Since that wasn't what I wanted anyway I tried setting things up manually like :

```
RenderSystem *rs = mRoot->getRenderSystemByName("OpenGL Rendering Subsystem");
mRoot->setRenderSystem(rs);
rs->setConfigOption("Full Screen","No");
rs->setConfigOption("Video Mode","1024 x 768");
```

Those matched the settings from 'ogre.cfg' that I was using prior from the showConfigDialog() function. I got the same issue with this manual configuration however, while loading the skybox textures it just stops.

I can't work out why these changes have any bearing at all on how the app runs and since OIS grabs the input and locks the mouse to the screen I am having trouble trying to debug it with gdb.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the mouse locking, you can run gdb on another display. It can either be a display on the same computer (including options like [Xephyr](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/Xephyr) that create virtual displays nested in the current display, or just a second session on a different display - if you have a working .xinitrc running two or three X sessions at a time is simple), or it can be on another machine on your network (ie. via ssh -X).